# Visually representing an open cover

Tags: general-topology, visualization

This is something that I have always found difficult. How would I go about illustrating an open cover $\mathfrak{A}$ when the number of elements in $
\mathfrak{A}$ could be infinite?

Here is the best attempt I have at visually representing an open cover:
[image]

To be clear, I am looking to see if there is a better representation than the one I have presenting.

Comment: would you be interested in a visualization of why you have a finite subcover of compact space?

Comment: @MikeMathMan I am afriad I don't quite understand your question. The way you have it worded is quite confusing.

Comment: Your basic infinite cover is to take an increasing set of open balls around a single point. So you start with the open ball or radius 1, then radius 2, etc.  This covers the entire space.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The Idea of a cover is more general than that presented in the context of a metric space. In other words you can have an open cover and not have the concept of an open ball of radius 1.

Comment: Sure, I was giving an intuitive example of an infinite cover. The intuitive example of a topology is a metric space - indeed, the above images indicates the same. @user160110

Comment: Throw blobs of different colored paint at a canvas until no bit of the canvas shows.  It is ok if some of the paint overlaps other blobs or hits the frame but please, no splashing, dribbling or dripping. If you like the effect, present the work at an art gallery, perhaps a university gallery, with the title "open cover".

Comment: If a set $A$ has the discrete topology, then one open cover is the set of singletons, even if $A$ is infinite.

Comment: @user160110: "Better" is in the eye of the beholder. Are you trying to depict some feature of a covering that is not conveyed by the "standard" [collection-of-disks diagram](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XhWl0.png)?

Comment: You might ask yourself the same question about any infinite set whatsoever, how would you represent that set visually? For example the set $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,4,...\}$ or $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{R}=(-\infty,+\infty)$ or $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$. The usual answer is: we draw some finite piece of it as an approximation; then maybe we use some mechanism such as "dots" to depict the undrawn parts, although that part seems to me not to always be necessary.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you your visual representation was something I was looking for. I don't exactly expect there to be one distinct answer to this question. I just expected people to post their own personal visualizations of compact sets when they are working on a problem that uses compactness.